# How to adjust time scale axis for ggplot histogram

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am working with a data frame where one of the columns consists of `POSIXct` date-time values.  I am trying to plot a histogram of these timestamps using `ggplot2` but I'm having two issues:

1. I don't know how to set the binwidth in `geom_histogram()`.  I'd like to set each bin to a day or a week.  I've tried providing a difftime object, but I get an error.  I also tried `binwidth=1` but R just hangs.
2. How do I set the limits in `scale_x_time()`?  The only way I could get it to work was by converting my `POSIXct` timestamps using `as.Date()`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770698/understanding-dates-and-plotting-a-histogram-with-ggplot2-in-r

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. The binwidth is measured in seconds, so to bin per week set `binwidth=7*24*60*60`.
2. Limits can be given as a vector of 2 POSIXct objects.

An example:

```
y<-as.POSIXct('1970/01/01')+cumsum(rnorm(100,mean=24*60*60,sd=24*60*60))
p<-qplot(y,binwidth=7*24*60*60,fill=I('steelblue'),col=I('black'))
p<-p+scale_x_datetime(major="1 week",
                      minor="1 days",
                      format="%e/%m/%Y",
                      limits=c(as.POSIXct('1970/02/01'),
                               as.POSIXct('1970/03/31')))
print(p)
```

Comment: %d gives a leading zero while %e gives a leading space on single digit days. Not really sure which one looks better.

Comment: Thanks! My issue with the scale was due to my using scale_x_time() rather than scale_x_datetime().

Comment: Thanks - in my case I didn't realize that the binwidth was in seconds when the data type is POSIXct.  So when I was setting binwidth=1, the plot would never finish because it was too granular.