# Can't draw histogram of Date Class properly in R

Tags: r

Given a list of dates, when I try to draw bar graph by hist() function as below,

```
date1 <- c(as.Date("2010/01/06"),as.Date("2010/01/07"),as.Date("2010/01/18"),as.Date("2010/01/09"))
hist(date1, "days",ylim=c(0,2),freq=T)
```

The output I get is the link below.

[image]

As the list has "2010/01/06" and "2010/01/07", the graph should count for each date.
How can I resolve this? or is this a bug of R?

My environment is:
Mac OS X 10.9.5
R version 2.15.3

Comment: I ran your code and saw dates like "Jan 06", "Jan 08", and "Jan 10" on the x-axis. I use Mac OS X 10.9.5 R version 3.1.2.

Comment: At least upgrade your `R` version and try again to see if the problem persists.  Also, after that, do `sessionInfo()` and paste the output into your question as an edit.  This helps with troubleshooting.

Comment: Is your concern the formatting of the x-axis or the binning of the data? If the latter, read `?hist` carefully, it doesn't always do what you think it might.  Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770698/understanding-dates-and-plotting-a-histogram-with-ggplot2-in-r?rq=1), linked at right.

Comment: @BryanHanson Thank you. My problem was the latter. I read the ?hist, and found that "If right = TRUE (default), the histogram cells are intervals of the form (a, b]". I got the graph I wanted by adding an option "right = F". Again, thank you for your advise. I will read manual carefully next time.

Comment: If you will be doing a lot of this, you'll probably need to figure out how to set the breaks in hist to be equal to the number of days between the earliest and latest observation so that every day corresponds to one bin.  For working with dates, I recommend the `lubridate` package.

Comment: @BryanHanson That's exactly what I'm going to do, and `lubridate` looks nice. I'll give it a try. Thank you for your kindness.