# Plotting Variable over Date:Time Issue in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to plot "breaks" counts that occur on a specific day over time. But get issues since the "Time" variable is in a date:time format and the graph fails to generate.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = `Breaks`, x = `Date`)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 100, binwidth = 1, colour = "white", fill = "#1380A1")
```

example data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1544107050, 1544100120, 1540557866, 
1540558168, 1544100123, 1544100135, 1545299546, 1545299518, 1545822865, 
1545822864, 1545822866, 1545822875, 1546016246, 1546016252, 1546016263
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Breaks = c(NA, 
NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the expected output of your data? Also, your code does not match your data (is the variable `Break` the same as the variable `Breaks`?). Furthermore, is there something missing after the last `+`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding dates and plotting a histogram with ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770698/understanding-dates-and-plotting-a-histogram-with-ggplot2-in-r)

Comment: I corrected the errors in the question. And the graph should be "Breaks" on the Y-axis and "Time" on the X-Axis. It should should a line graph/histogram of how many "Breaks" occur on a specific day.

Comment: @divibisan that question is counting the dates as a numeric. Mine is adding a 2nd variable over time

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to make a histogram that bins by a date value. Can you clarify your question to show how it's different and why those answers aren't helpful?

Comment: Maybe look up what a histogram is? It's very different from a line plot. It doesn't take a y variable at all. And it uses bars, not lines. Perhaps you want a barplot, one bar per day, with the height of the bar being the number of non-missing `Breaks` values? Or maybe you want the height of the bar to be the *sum* of non-missing Breaks values? Or something else?

Comment: I am seeing nothing wrong with @divibisan's dupe. Should I VTC? (I can do it on my own.)

Comment: @Gregor "Perhaps you want a barplot, one bar per day, with the height of the bar being the number of non-missing Breaks values?" <--  This is what i'm looking for. But I need the missing values in the graph that represent (o) essentially

Comment: What's wrong with `ggplot(df, aes(x = as.Date(Date))) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, aes(fill = "#1380A1"))`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas it counts the number of times "2018-12-06" there are in the dataset and plots it. It does not count the amount of "Breaks" that occur on the day over time which is the objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  count(Date, wt = Breaks) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, n)) +
  geom_col(colour = "white", fill = "#1380A1")
```

[image]

(Not sure I'm understanding the comment about "But I need the missing values in the graph that represent (o) essentially." Should zeros be represented visually somehow? BTW, the part through the `count(Date = ...` line produces this -- is that what you meant by capturing the missing values?)

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Date           n
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2018-10-26     2
2 2018-12-06     0
3 2018-12-20     0
4 2018-12-26     0
5 2018-12-28     1
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you