# how to make histogram with dates in format aaaa-mm-dd in R

Tags: r, date, histogram

I have a database with dates of florestal burn. I want make a histogram wiht this dates, would like verify such as month most fire burn.

my dates : 2010/09/21
2010/09/21
2010/09/21
2010/09/21
2010/09/21
2010/09/21
2010/09/21
2010/10/18
2011/07/08
2011/07/08
2011/07/09
2011/07/09
2011/08/06
2011/08/13
2011/08/16
2011/08/16
2011/08/31
2011/08/31
2011/09/13
2011/09/13
2011/09/13
2011/09/13
2012/09/10
2012/09/08
2012/10/01
2012/11/22
2013/02/19
2013/03/05
2013/08/03
2013/08/14
2014/08/20
2013/09/13
2015/03/16
2015/03/14
2015/08/13
2020/04/11
2020/04/18
2020/04/18
2020/04/22
2020/04/22
2020/04/23
2020/04/23
2020/04/23
2020/04/27
2020/04/27
2020/04/27
2020/04/29
2020/04/29
2020/05/11
2020/04/28
2020/04/28
2020/06/12
2020/06/12
2020/06/12
2020/06/12
2020/08/11
2020/08/15
2020/08/15
2020/08/15
2020/08/29
2020/08/29
2020/08/29
2020/08/29
2015/10/19
2017/09/10
2018/03/23
2018/06/24
2018/09/11
2018/11/11
2018/11/11
2019/02/06
2019/02/22
2019/03/12
2019/04/14
2019/07/31
2019/07/31
2019/07/31
2016/11/06
2017/07/13
2017/07/13
2017/07/13
2017/07/24
2017/07/24
2017/08/30
2017/08/30
2017/08/30
2017/08/30
2017/03/25

Comment: Are you sure you want a histogram? Would a barplot of each month work for you? E.g.: `barplot(table(format(as.Date(x), "%Y-%m")), las=2)`?

Comment: yes, i need histogram between year 2010 and 2020.

Comment: Consider this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770698/understanding-dates-and-plotting-a-histogram-with-ggplot2-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `hist.Date` method.

```
hist(as.Date(d), breaks="months", xlab="Date", main="Forestal burn")
```

[image]

---

*Example data:*

```
d <- c("2010/09/21", "2010/09/21", "2010/09/21", "2010/09/21", "2010/09/21", 
"2010/09/21", "2010/09/21", "2010/10/18", "2011/07/08", "2011/07/08", 
"2011/07/09", "2011/07/09", "2011/08/06", "2011/08/13", "2011/08/16", 
"2011/08/16", "2011/08/31", "2011/08/31", "2011/09/13", "2011/09/13", 
"2011/09/13", "2011/09/13", "2012/09/10", "2012/09/08", "2012/10/01", 
"2012/11/22", "2013/02/19", "2013/03/05", "2013/08/03", "2013/08/14", 
"2014/08/20", "2013/09/13", "2015/03/16", "2015/03/14", "2015/08/13", 
"2020/04/11", "2020/04/18", "2020/04/18", "2020/04/22", "2020/04/22", 
"2020/04/23", "2020/04/23", "2020/04/23", "2020/04/27", "2020/04/27", 
"2020/04/27", "2020/04/29", "2020/04/29", "2020/05/11", "2020/04/28", 
"2020/04/28", "2020/06/12", "2020/06/12", "2020/06/12", "2020/06/12", 
"2020/08/11", "2020/08/15", "2020/08/15", "2020/08/15", "2020/08/29", 
"2020/08/29", "2020/08/29", "2020/08/29", "2015/10/19", "2017/09/10", 
"2018/03/23", "2018/06/24", "2018/09/11", "2018/11/11", "2018/11/11", 
"2019/02/06", "2019/02/22", "2019/03/12", "2019/04/14", "2019/07/31", 
"2019/07/31", "2019/07/31", "2016/11/06", "2017/07/13", "2017/07/13", 
"2017/07/13", "2017/07/24", "2017/07/24", "2017/08/30", "2017/08/30", 
"2017/08/30", "2017/08/30", "2017/03/25")
```

Comment: how did you manage to organize the data in "d"?
I'm a newbie in R.

Comment: @wesleysc352 Try `(v <- unname(unlist(read.table(text="2010/09/21 2010/09/21 2010/09/21"))))`. How did my solution work for you?

Comment: sorry but i have a csv table with many dates, how would i do it automatically to generate "d" the same way you did? I am very lost in this matter.

Comment: @wesleysc352 Hey, you asked about how to make a histogram with dates, didn't you? If that worked you may accept the answer (_help_: [how-to accept-an-aswer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)) and ask the topic in a new question, that's how it works here, you know ;)

Comment: yes it worked, but I can't generate this "d". Would I have to do it manually?

Comment: Nice answer. It might be cleaner to format the x-axis as month-year too - `hist(as.Date(d), breaks="months", las=2, format="%m-%y")`

Comment: @wesleysc352 - the `d` represents your date field in your dataset. Import your data like `dat <- read.csv("filename.csv")` then replace `d` with `dat$datevariablename` where `datevariablename` is the column containing your date information.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for the pointer, just noticed the `format` argument, really cool! For those interested in all the arguments: run `?hist.Date`.

Comment: i add freq=TRUE in code to calculate frequency---> hist(as.Date(d), breaks="months", xlab="Date", main="Forestal burn", freq=TRUE), thaks